# How can this code be reversed? (recursion)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion

Got code from Pierre Fourgeaud (internet) but I can't understand how it can be reversed?

```
void reverse( string& word )
{
    if ( word.size() <= 1 ) return;

    // Get the string without the first and the last char
    string temp = word.substr( 1, word.size() - 2 );

    // Reverse it
    reverse( temp );

    // Recompose the string
    word = word.substr( word.size() - 1 ) + temp + word[0];
}
```

Comment: It computes `last + middle + first` while also reversing the middle. What's the problem?

Comment: what is 'it; and why don't you understand how 'it' can be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it's the recursion that confuse you. So, here's an example:

```
string word = "world";
```

- First recursion will split `"world"` to: `"w" , "orl" and "d"` and it will pass `"orl"` to the second recursion.
- Second recursion will split `"orl"` to: `"o" , "r"  and "l"` and it will pass `"r"` to the third recursion.
- Third recursion will do nothing since `size of "r" <= 1`. And, now you go back to second recursion
- Second recursion now will swap `"o"` and `"l"` and leave `"r"` as it is, which means: `"lro"` and this goes back to the first recursion.
- Finally first recursion will swap `"w"` and `"d"` and leave `"lro"` as it is, which means: `"dlrow"`. Which is the reversed of `"world"`